# How to change mimeType of a file in Google Drive using the REST API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file named `config.json` with the mimeType: `application/octet-stream`.

[Google API Explorer - Get File Metatadatas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMfZu.png)

```
 GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1b95F40yMjPYhdZjn8zZPr6P3wjUnxoM2
```

and the response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1b95F40yMjPYhdZjn8zZPr6P3wjUnxoM2",
 "name": "config.json",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

I want to change it to `application/json`.

[Google API Explorer - Change File Metatadatas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZSTy.png)

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1b95F40yMjPYhdZjn8zZPr6P3wjUnxoM2

{
 "mimeType": "application/json"
}
```

But the mimeType didn't change...

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1b95F40yMjPYhdZjn8zZPr6P3wjUnxoM2",
 "name": "config.json",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Was my workaround useful for you? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 2):

Also in my environment, the mimeType cannot be changed by `drive.files.update`. So I always use this workaround. Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for you, how about this?

#### Use `drive.files.copy`

Endpoint is as follows.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###/copy
```

Request body is as follows.

```
{
 "mimeType": "application/json",
 "name": "samplename.json"
}
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Added:

#### Confirm:

At first, the mimeType of `fileId1` is confirm. By the way, as a sample situation, this file is a PNG file. I uploaded this by changing the mimeType to `application/octet-stream`. This is used as the sample file.

Curl command:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId1 \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Result:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "###",
 "name": "samplefile",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

- From above curl command, it is found that the file of `fileId1` has the mimeType of `application/octet-stream`.

#### Convert mimeType:

Curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId1/copy \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"mimeType":"application/json","name":"samplename.json"}' \
  --compressed
```

Result:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "fileId2",
 "name": "samplename.json",
 "mimeType": "application/json"
}
```

- When above curl command is run for the file of `fileId1`, it was changed that the mimeType was changed from `application/octet-stream` to `application/json`.

### Note:

- There are 3 important points.

  1. **OP wants to change the mimeType of `application/octet-stream` to `application/json`. This answer is for achieving this goal. Please be careful this.**
  2. In this case, when the mimeType is changed, the data format is not changed. So please be also careful this.
  3. All mimeTypes cannot be changed. So please be also careful this.
- For example, when the mimeType of excel file (`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and `application/vnd.ms-excel`) can be converted to Google Spreadsheet (`application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`). But the image file cannot be directly converted to Google Spreadsheet.
- From [`it doesn't work for me. looks like the mimeType property is not working.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916708/how-to-change-mimetype-of-a-file-in-google-drive-using-the-rest-api/48916906#comment107560759_48916906), I cannot understand about [Mahdi Abdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2743815/mahdi-abdi)'s situation. So if you want to change the mimeType except for `application/octet-stream` to the mimeType except for `application/json`, this answer might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.
looks like the `mimeType` property is not working.

Comment: @Mahdi Abdi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that this method worked. So I had proposed this. as the confirmation of above flow, I added more information. Could you please confirm it? By the way, from your comment of `it doesn't work for me. looks like the mimeType property is not working.`, I cannot understand about your situation. So can you provide the detail information for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.